# replacing the specific word with tag

Tags: javascript

I have a string below with some words inside the curly brace, i want to extract the words and make it as array

**input**:

```
 let string = 'Hello John \n, the time is ${time} and its ${day} of ${month} ${year}'
```

**output**:

```
let keys = ["time", "day", "month", "year"]
```

what is the right approach to do in regex to achieve it.

And how can i replace the string with the input tags, like shown below.

```
  let string = 'Hello John \n, the time is <input name='time' /> and its <input name='day' /> of <input name='month' /> <input name='year' />'
```

Comment: Tip: [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can take a function as a substitution argument.

Comment: @tadman but replace can do .replace('text', 'newText'), but how can i .replace('${?}') dynamic things

Comment: With a function instead of a string. Look at the MDN examples. There's a few like that.

Answer (score 3):

You could capture all matched groups

```js
const string = 'Hello John \n, the time is ${time} and its ${day} of ${month} ${year}'
const regex = /\$\{(\w+)\}/g
const res = [];
let matches

while (matches = regex.exec(string)) {
  res.push(matches[1]);
}

console.log(res)
```

And about replacing, do a string `.replace` with modifed catupered group using dollar sign (`$`) with the order of captured group (1-based index)

```js
const string = 'Hello John \n, the time is ${time} and its ${day} of ${month} ${year}'
const res = string.replace(/\$\{(\w+)\}/g, '<input name="$1"/>')

console.log(res)
```